# YARN REST API - submit simple job

Tags: java, api, rest, submit, hadoop-yarn

I need help with the http request body filling.
I am doing a PUT http request and I know that I am doing it right (in java).

I want to run the simple map reduce job example – calculate PI…
When I use the command :

“hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar pi 10 10”

In the hortonworks terminal it works, I try to create and run a job that does the same.

I think the problem is in the request body (in the run_mapreducer_M2.txt file). 
I am trying to use if with the [YARN REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_APISubmit_Application).

What am I missing? Does someone have an example for using a simple MR job?

Thanks!
Here is the XML file I am using for the request body:

```html
<application-submission-context>    
 <application-id>application_1421661392788_0005</application-id>
    <application-name>pi2</application-name> 
 <queue>testqueue</queue>
    <priority>3</priority>
    <am-container-spec>      
  <environment>   
   <entry>     
    <key>CLASSPATH</key>
    <value>/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/conf&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/lib/*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/.//*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-hdfs/./&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-hdfs/.//*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-yarn/lib/*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-yarn/.//*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*&lt;CPS&gt;&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/current/tez-client/*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/current/tez-client/lib/*&lt;CPS&gt;/etc/tez/conf/&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/tez/*&lt;CPS&gt;/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/tez/lib/*&lt;CPS&gt;/etc/tez/conf</value>
   </entry>
  </environment>
  <commands>
   <command>hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar pi 10 10</command>
  </commands>
    </am-container-spec>
    <unmanaged-AM>false</unmanaged-AM>
    <max-app-attempts>2</max-app-attempts>
    <resource>      
  <memory>1024</memory>
  <vCores>1</vCores>
    </resource>    
 <application-type>MAPREDUCE</application-type>
    <keep-containers-across-application-attempts>false</keep-containers-across-application-attempts>
    <application-tags>      
  <tag>Michael</tag>      
  <tag>PI example</tag>    
 </application-tags>
</application-submission-context>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if this is late, you've probably found the answer already but you want to use a POST http request instead of PUT.